# What is the ruling if we broke a non-obligatory fast by performing sexual intercourse?

Tags: sawm

I and my husband performed sunnah fasting but after fajr prayer we had sexual intercourse, What are the Islamic rules after that?

Comment: Well if you had intercourse after fajr prayer you have not fasted, but intended to fast that day as it seems. As you've certainly broken your fast.

Answer (score 1):

Sexual intercourse breaks the fast, and you have to make up for it on another day. If it was Ramadan, you'd also be liable for expiation (freeing a just slave, fasting 60 consecutive days or feeding 60 poor people). Although it isn't, I'm mentioning this so that you're aware of the consequences of you were to repeat this during Ramadan.

Comment: The question is about voluntary fasts. Your answer misses the topic of the question completely.

Comment: I'm confused by your comment. Sex is not allowed during any fast, and breaks a Nafl fast. I merely mentioned the case of Ramadan because it is coming up soon.

Comment: Well it should be clear that the fast is not valid the point is whether or not an expiation is necessary. By answering a different question your post creates confusion you should stick on answering the given question.